# 500 when trying to send message to bot via Direct Line API

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I'm building a client which will interact with an existing bot built using the Microsoft Bot Framework. The bot works fine when I test with the existing channels. I can also successfully start a conversation when using the Direct Line API. However when I try to send a message to the bot using Direct Line API I get a 500 error with content "ServiceError".

I am sending an http Post request using Fiddler to https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/[MyConversationID]/activities with the following header:

```
Authorization: Bearer <My Secret> 
Host: directline.botframework.com
Content-Length: 97
```

And Body

```
{
    "type": "message",
    "from": {
        "id": "user1"
    },
    "text": "hello"
}
```

I am fairly certain the issue is not in my bot code as no breakpoint is hit. Has anyone had a similar issue? Or have any advice on how to go about debugging it?

Comment: Are u using C# or Node? Just in case, because if you are using any of those, then you can use other mechanisms than the REST API to talk with Direct Line.

Comment: My bot is built with C# and the client will also be built in C#. At the moment I'm just using Fiddler to send Http Requests to my c# bot using Direct Line.